# Does declaring a hash with curly braces require assignment?

Tags: ruby, hash, variable-declaration

I thought I could declare a hash using either {} or Hash[], but curly braces doesn't seem to work unless I assign it to a variable (see below). I'm guessing irb gets confused about whether it's a hash or a block. Is that correct, or am I declaring the hash with curly braces incorrectly?

```
>> puts h = { :a=>1, :b=>2 }
{:a=>1, :b=>2}

>> puts { :a=>1, :b=>2 }
SyntaxError: (irb):58: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
puts { :a=>1, :b=>2 }
           ^
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

>> puts Hash[ :a=>1, :b=>2 ]
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this by adding parentheses:

```
puts({ :a => 1, :b => 2 })
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

If you leave off the parentheses, Ruby will interpret the curly braces as a block:

```
puts { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
# SyntaxError: unexpected ':', expecting '}'

# semantically the same as

puts do
  :a => 1, :b => 2
end
# SyntaxError: unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
```

But you can also *omit* both parentheses and Ruby will treat it as a Hash:

```
puts :a => 1, :b => 2
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}

# same as

puts(:a => 1, :b => 2)
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}

# same as

puts({:a => 1, :b => 2})
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

And you can even use short notation for symbol keys ;-)

```
puts a: 1, b: 2
# {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9-style hashes like `a: 1` may take some getting used to, but they're actually really convenient. It also makes things more consistent with other languages like Objective-C and JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman: Except that they're not that useful if you're using MongoDB and have to say `:$inc => ...`, `'some.path' => ...` and such all the time. Or if things like `a: :b` make your eyes bleed. Get off my lawn, etc. :)

Comment: @muistooshort Sure, you get some oddities like `a: :b ? :c : :d` if you're not careful, but the new syntax isn't impossible to acclimatize to. Plus, you can mix and match: `a: :b, '$c' => :d`.

Comment: Good answer. Does anyone know why it was decided to require parentheses for methods (such as `puts`) that don't take a block?

Comment: @CarySwoveland because the lexer/parser do not know whether the method takes a block or not, let alone that Ruby allows you to redefine methods dynamically. Heck, you are even allowed to pass a block to a method that never uses it. I think it is also good to keep things consistent and not introduce even more special cases. Ruby simply requires you to be verbose where ambiguities may occur.

Answer (score 2):

It just requires unambiguous syntax, e.g.,

```
irb> puts({ :a => 1, :b => 2 })
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your puts { ... } looks to ruby as though you are passing a block of code.  Since puts is a method that can take arguments and/or a block you need to specify that the stuff inside the curly brackets is intended to be an argument and not a block.  Try:

```
puts( { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `puts` with a block.